# Meta keywords single words or phrase?

Tags: keywords, best-practices, meta-tags

It is acceptable or recommended to only use 1 keyword per delimiter? Or can we use a phrase?

For example:

```
car, Audi, Ferrari, Lamborgini
```

**vs**

```
Audi Car, Ferrari Car, Lamborgini Car
```

What is considered best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter since meta keywords have no effect on a page's rankings.

So, use whichever one you think describes something properly. "Ferrari car" doesn't do that as Ferrari is a brand name and can stand alone. "Blue widget" and "green widget" should obviously not be broken down into "widget, blue, green" as that wouldn't make any real sense.