# Meta keywords random keywords

Tags: seo, meta-tags, meta-keywords, random

I was wondering what about having random meta keywords instead of fixed one?

I have a blog, so every blog post has some related tags, in my home page i show the post's previews, so i put in meta keywords all the main blog post's tags i show.

Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Meta Keywords are useless for SEO, and random meta keywords are useless for everything!!!*

Read wikipedia:

> in September 2009 Matt Cutts of **Google announced that they are no
>   longer taking keywords into account whatsoever**...
>   In Oct 2009...Yahoo!'s Senior Director...states that "...What
>   changed with **Yahoo's ranking algorithms is that while we still index
>   the meta keyword tag, the ranking importance given to meta keyword
>   tags receives the lowest ranking signal in our system**.... it will
>   actually have less effect than introducing those same words in the
>   body of the document, or any other section."

from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element

Or dozens of other questions here on Webmasters:

- [Do meta keywords have any impact on ranking algorithms?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6/do-meta-keywords-have-any-impact-on-ranking-algorithms)
- [Meta keywords single words or phrase?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20662/meta-keywords-single-words-or-phrase)

Comment: I think Wikipedia is a little misleading... in the September 2009 blogpost (that Wikipedia cites), Matt Cutts states that, "Google has ignored the keywords meta tag for years".

Comment: @w3d: well even worse than (and thanks for the editing)

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't take into account meta keywords tag for SEO and that for many years (since 2009). You just can delete it.

Moreover, keywords you use in this meta gives keywords ideas for your contestants.

You can read this: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html.

Comment: Google has ignored the keywords meta tag long before 2009... in the September 2009 blogpost (that you link to), Matt Cutts states that, "...many years ago Google began disregarding the keywords meta tag".